# Is it possible to convert a PDF document to Word using Java?

Tags: java, pdf

I have searched online about this, however I have not found anything so far on how to effectively convert any PDF document (The PDF document might contain text, images, charts) to a Word document. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: "_Please do not mark my question as a bad question if you do not know the answer to this or if you do not want to answer this._" – That's not why people downvote and/or vote to close; people downvote and/or vote to close when the question does not meet Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: You may take a look at [Spire.PDF for Java API](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-java.html) and the documentation: [Convert PDF to Word in Java](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Java/Spire.PDF-for-Java/Program-Guide/Conversion/Convert-PDF-to-Word-in-Java.html)